# How to add product image sales order grid in magento 1.8.1?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.8

How to add product image sales order grid in magento 1.8.1?
 I tried to below code but showing blank image i want here which product sold?

```
public function callback_thumbnail($value, $row, $column, $isExport) {
  $product_id = $value;
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
   $url = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,     'thumbnail')>resize(70,70);
    return "<img src='$url' />";
     }  
     $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
         'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Thumbnail'),
          'index' => 'entity_id',
          'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_thumbnail')
       ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-ordergrid-with-images.html